# Can't locate a 1026 error requesting assistance with location

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can't seem to find the source of the 1026 error:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
stop();
var NueMCSpeed:Number = 10;
var _movingUp:Boolean = false;
var _movingDown:Boolean = false;
var _movingLeft:Boolean = false;
var _movingRight:Boolean = false;
var _focused:Boolean = false;
var _attacking:Boolean = false;
var ShootAllow:Boolean = true;
var timer:Number = 2;
var shotN:Number = 0;
var SHOTINDEX:Number  = 0;
NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
var _root:Object;
var speed:int = 10;
Mainp();
function Mainp()
{
    //var NueMC:MovieClip;

    // add listeners
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myOnPress);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, myOnRelease);
}
function createPlayer():void
{
    var NueMC:MovieClip;
    NueMC.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    NueMC.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    stage.addChild(NueMC);
}

function myOnPress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch ( event.keyCode )
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            _movingUp = true;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            _movingDown = true;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            _movingLeft = true;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueL");
            break;

        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            _movingRight = true;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueR");
            break;

        case Keyboard.SHIFT :
            _focused = true;
            break;

        case Keyboard.Z :
            _attacking = true;
            //timer++
            //if(timer == 3){
                //shoot();
                //timer = 0
            //}
            break;
    }
}
function myOnRelease(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch ( event.keyCode )
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            _movingUp = false;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            _movingDown = false;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            _movingLeft = false;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            _movingRight = false;
            NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueG");
            break;

        case Keyboard.SHIFT :
            _focused = false;
            break;

        case Keyboard.Z :
            _attacking = false;
            break;
    }
}
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (_focused == true)
    {
        NueMCSpeed = 5;
        ShootAllow = true
    }
    if (_focused == false)
    {
        NueMCSpeed = 10;
    }
    if ( _movingLeft && !_movingRight )
    {
        NueMC.x -=  NueMCSpeed;
    }
    if ( _movingRight && !_movingLeft )
    {
        NueMC.x +=  NueMCSpeed;
    }
    if ( _movingUp && !_movingDown )
    {
        NueMC.y -=  NueMCSpeed;
    }
    if ( _movingDown && !_movingUp )
    {
        NueMC.y +=  NueMCSpeed;
    }
    if(NueMC.y < 165)
{
    NueMC.y = 165
}
if(NueMC.y > 885)
{
    NueMC.y = 885
}
if(NueMC.x > 520)
{
    NueMC.x = 520
}
if(NueMC.x < 10)
{
    NueMC.x = 10
}


    // Move diagonally
    if ( _movingLeft && _movingUp && !_movingRight && !_movingDown )
    {

    }
    if ( _movingRight && _movingUp && !_movingLeft && !_movingDown )
    {

    }
    if ( _movingLeft && _movingDown && !_movingRight && !_movingUp )
    {

    }
    if ( _movingRight && _movingDown && !_movingLeft && !_movingUp )
    {

    }

}

var pIsDead:Boolean = false;

var LSP:Number = .1;

var NP:Number = .0001;

var vx:Number = NueMC.x;

var vy:Number = NueMC.y;

var BHPN:Number = BHP.scaleX

if(ShootAllow == true && _attacking == true)
{
stageRef.addChild(new Bullet(stageRef, x + vx, y + vy));
ShootAllow = false;
}
if (NueMC.NHB.hitTestObject(stage.DBS.DBHB) && NueLB.scaleX > .1)

{

NueLB.scaleX -= LSP;
Score -=10000;
NueMC.gotoAndStop("NueDie");
pIsDead = true;

}
```

And then in an .as file I have:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Bullet2 extends flash.display.MovieClip
    {


        private var stageRef2:Stage;
        private var bulletSpeed:Number = 20;
        public function Bullet2(stageRef:Stage, xd:Number, yd:Number):void
        {

            this.stageRef = stageRef2;

            this.x = xd;

            this.y = yd;


            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

        }


        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {

            y -=  bulletSpeed;

            if (y < 125)
            {
                removeSelf();
            }
        }


        private function removeSelf():void
        {

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);


            if (stageRef.contains(this))
            {
                stageRef.removeChild(this);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

I need to finish this program soon so help is greatly appreciated. PS code is long as I have no idea where the error is since flash doesn't want to give me the line.

Comment: Questions about debugging on Stack Overflow require a [mcve]. The code that you have posted is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the code **in your question** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more). As it is your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You have to debug your code to get the exact line of that error, it's not to us to do that !

Comment: sorry new to this site. and also I only asked because it wont give me the line number for some reason. p.s. I only put the code in without shortening it because I have no idea where the error could be.

Comment: @xxslimferretxx To debug your code in Flash IDE : menu **Debug** >> **Debug Movie** >> **Debug** or **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**, and you'll get the line concerned by that error ...

Comment: @akmozo thanks i'll be sure to try that asap. (aka monday)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line: `function Mainp()` The problem is that it is located on the timeline, you cannot place constructors on the timeline. You should find the main `*.as` file and place that `Mainp()` in there, inside the `class Mainp` definition.